# Parcheesi: Doubles bonus

Tags: house-rules, parcheesi

We are playing Milton Bradley “Parcheesi” and have an ambiguity in the rules to settle.

> DOUBLETS
> A roll of matching dice is called
> doublets.

> • If you roll doublets before all of your
> pawns are entered, take your turn
> as usual, then roll again.

> • Doublets Bonus: If you roll doublets
> **after all four of your pawns are
> entered**, use the four numbers on the
> tops and the bottoms of the dice for
> movement. The total of this four-part
> move is always 14, and can be taken
> by one pawn or split among 2 or
> more pawns.

Ok, so if you get all four of your pawns out, have you triggered the Doublets Bonus for the rest of the game?

Or, if you get pawns sent back to the nest, are they no longer considered “entered” and your bonus is shut-down until the pawns are entered a second time?

- Wikipedia says that all the pawns have to be out of the field, but that’s not exactly what the rules say.

[FG](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/Parcheesi.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to claim that the phrasing "are entered" refers to the state of the four pieces, not an event (in which case it could have been phrased "If you roll doublets before all four of the pieces *have been entered*").

Thus, if a piece is sent home, it is no longer the case that all four of the pieces *are* entered, and you lose the doublet bonus until such time as all four pieces are again entered.

Note that a piece reaching home is not "unentered", so the distinction is between pieces in the nest and pieces out of the nest, not pieces in play  and pieces not in play.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).